# How do I merge a question into another on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, merged-questions

On a [recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105120/what-is-undefined-behavior), the question came up how to merge the answers of one question into another.

A quick (search https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[faq]+merge) didn't reveal anything, so I'm asking this here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "merged" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag it for a moderator; this is a pretty rare action (compared to general site activity), that is described [in the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/)