# Where does a supplementary question belong?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

If I see a question about a certain topic and want to ask a supplementary question about it, where should I ask it? I'm afraid a new question will be marked as a duplicate, and heavily downvoted so that it is not shown in the list of questions on the homepage.

Should the supplementary question be asked as an answer to the earlier question? Or should it be posted as a comment? What if a user cannot do this, because of low reputation?

---

This might have been asked before, but I could not find any meaningful results when searching for ["supplementary question"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvnoG.png). Also, while writing this question I have checked the list of ["Questions that may already have your answer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htrL8.png). I found two identical questions which look similar (after using Google Translate to my native language), but their content is different from what I'm asking here.

Comment: The answer to this question seems to have already been provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313256/389569), even though the question that prompted it is not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @JasonBassford : It is not in the power of one person to study the whole SE (thousands of thousands of questions) and to find responses in the comments below answers.

Therefore, there is a search engine and lexical content analysis.

Nothing found here. (See pictures.)

But the human brain works differently, so it finds duplication wherever the machine evaluates it as harmless/unobjectionable.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this question can be trimmed down to just the last two paragraphs.

Comment: I mean, it's great that you shared your research so far, but it shouldn't occupy 90% of the question body.

Comment: Presumably, if you are simply asking a *supplementary question* it is mostly the same as the original, but with a specifically slight enough addition that a new question is required. Therefore, you can assume that it is not a duplicate of anything (else your original would have likely been closed as such), and you should link to the first one and then ask the additional question on the same topic. If the new question is not that close to the original, then *supplementary* doesn't seem like the right word to me.

Comment: @Glorfindel : Firstly, the effort to be induplicative. Secondly, show the downvoters an effort that the question was being sought and that the search engine and lexical analyzer do not work well. In order not to give negative points that it is duplicite question again.

Comment: That makes sense; please let me try to rework your question so that it's both to the point *and* shows your research. I suspect the one downvote you got is because right now it's not clear what you're asking *at all* until your get to the last two paragraphs.

Comment: For Glorfindel I resize pictures, not to take so much space.

Comment: In this case it is better not to show them, but only link to them. They are important because they show you've done your work, but they distract from your real question. I hope you like the new version; if not, you can always roll back to an earlier version with [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/313351/revisions). You'll notice that I've changed some of the words to better match the Stack Exchange terminology ('answer' instead of 'response', 'reputation' instead of 'rating').

Comment: My question itself shows the problem that I describe at the beginning. It is recursive.

Comment: Yes it is ok. It has an informative value. It is written by a native speaker rather than a machine (translator). It has a connection to your answer. And you have another notch for the Illuminator badge. ;-) I think that this question will be of benefit to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does a supplementary question belong?

(Usually) on the same site as the original question, as a new question.
It's even part of the canned comment from the Low Quality Posts review (when a question is posted as an answer):

> #### This is a different question posted as an answer
>
> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Sometimes, it *might* work to leave a comment under the answer, and together with the author of the answer extend both the question and the answer. I'd do this only if the supplementary question is a 'logical consequence' of the main question and considerably smaller than it. Also, when there are more answers to your question, this can get messy.

Comment: Note: There are times when the 'supplementary question' belongs on a different SE site. For example, if one asks how to do something on [su] and gets an answer that requires user input, but they also want to know how to make some software they're writing do it programmatically, they should ask about that on [so], providing a link to the original question on [su] for context.