# What happens to the comments when two questions are merged?

Tags: support, comments, merged-questions

When two questions are merged, answers from the source question are moved to the target question.

**Question.** Is the same true for the comments? Are the comments under the source question moved to the target question when two questions are merged.

Although I assume that if this is the case, typically the moderator handling the merger cleans up the comments which no longer make sense on the target question.

The FAQ post [What is a “merged” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158066#158067) ([current revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/158067/10)) explains that: "All of the merged question's answers, including their votes and comments, become answers to the target question." However, it does not mention the comments under the question - only the comments under the answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure comments are too. I have seen comments on posts that made absolutely no sense in the context, but then the revision history showed a merge, and they did make sense with the original post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the non-deleted comments under the question are moved to the target question too. I have edited the FAQ(-proposed) answer to clarify that.