# Attempting to edit a Merged question shows wrong error: "Suggested edit queue is full"

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits, error-message, merged-questions

[Difference between URI and URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984213/difference-between-uri-and-url) has been [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question), but also shows "Possible Duplicate" within the question text.

I went to edit out the in-question duplicate. But pressing the edit button shows the error:

> Suggested edit queue is full

[image: Suggested edit queue is full]

The post is locked, as well as merged. When I attempt to edit a [non-merged locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), the much better error text is given:

> Post is locked.

I have edit privileges on SO, so I don't believe the Suggested Edit Queue should be involved in this process at all. So I'm assuming it's a bad error message, not the fact that the queue is actually full or that my edit would be queued.

Comment: Well... the message now says `Post is locked.` So either someone fixed this really quickly, or it *is* actually somewhat (incorrectly?) tied to the Suggested Edit Queue.

Comment: Potentially related cross-site issue: [Trying to edit a locked post results in an incorrect tooltip: "Suggested edit queue is full"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350564/) (MSO)