Should we do anything to promote useful answers on duplicate questions?
I previously asked this on Space Exploration Meta as Should we do anything for answers on duplicate questions?. The basic train of thought is as follows:

A question was closed as a duplicate. During the vote-to-close an answer was added. After the question was closed, discussion continued on that answer for ways to improve it.
Given the seeming reasons for voting-to-close as a duplicate, it seemed to me that spending effort improving an answer to a question that was not likely to be re-opened would be better spent improving answers on the question we point people to.

Am I even correct about the reasoning for closing duplicate questions? If so, is it worthwhile to try to concentrate useful answers to those families of questions after-the-fact? Or is the status quo where all of these questions should be linked to each other and they can be visited and checked to see if they have useful answers good enough?

do you mean improving "canonical" / duplicate-target questions (I.e. the question that a duplicate question is closed as a duplicate of)?

@starball only in the sense that that canonical question might be improved by having the answer merged with it, as you pointed me to in your comment on my self-answer

I should think that how this is handled would be site-dependent, and this question should be asked in the Meta for the site in question. For example, in [SciFi.SE], it's normal to not close a question as duplicate until we get a confirmed answer that is the same work as the proposed duplicate; the reasoning for this is explained in a question in the SciFi meta (which I can't seem to dig up a link for at the moment).

My only idea so far is to somehow move useful answers for duplicates into the original question to better-reward the answerer, assuming their answer isn't also basically a duplicate of an existing one. (I feel reasonably certain such not-duplicate answers to certain commonly-duplicated questions exist on Space Exploration StackExchange; this may be less common on other sites).
It seems like there's some obvious pitfalls; even relatively close duplicates still have distinct enough contexts that entirely divorcing an answer from its original question will be confusing.  I have no idea how it would work out technically either, or what the workflow would be for doing it.

that's called merging. check your site meta for guidance on merging. Ex. on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312091/11107541

How merging questions works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158066/what-is-a-merged-question

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog so perhaps "Should we be less afraid of merging?" or "Should we merge more often" or "Are we merging enough?" might be a better title or a new question? But before that, maybe a SEDE check for what fraction of well-received answers on closed questions were ever merged (just enough to support the assertion that it's probably quite small). Different but related: Have there been analyses to see if views of well-received answers are reduced by closure as duplicate which try to control for other factors?

The merging we have seems overly destructive to me, now that I know about it.

@ErinAnne I think the first step would be to take a half-dozen cases of merging in an SE site you're familiar with, and look at the edit history to see what was done. I think any conscientious moderator can do a faithful job of merging when the situation allows it. It's a bit like surgery and I think mods are hesitant because it is by nature heavy-handed and the opposite of "light-touch", but I don't think it should be quickly labeled "destructive" much less overly-so, until you've examined several examples.
